# assign value to variable on variable declaration

Tags: php, oop

i was trying to declare variable as below:

```
class GumballMachine {

private static $SOLD_OUT = 0;
private $state = $SOLD_OUT;
    private function GumballMachine (){}
}
```

How can i assign value of $SOLD_OUT to $state or Is there other way to do so ?

Comment: Did you try echo'ing the variables in the constructor to see what you get? That will answer your question.

Comment: are you trying to create an enumeration type function? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

```
    const SOLD_OUT = 0;
    private $state = self::SOLD_OUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`class GumballMachine {

 private static $SOLD_OUT = 0;
 private $state = 0;
private function GumballMachine ()
 {
  $this->state=$SOLD_OUT;
 }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a constant value. Additionally, you need to declare your constructor as public or you will run into errors.

```
class GumballMachine {
    const SOLD_OUT = 0;

    private $state = self::SOLD_OUT;

    public function GumballMachine () { }
}
```